# Toggle Bootstrap modal with php trigger

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, twitter-bootstrap

I need to trigger a Bootstrap modal if a PHP GET url is set but I don't know how to.

The PHP code look's like this:

```
<?php
if ($_GET['activate']) {
$activate = $_GET['activate'];
    mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `active` = 1 WHERE `email_code` = '$activate'");
}
?>
```

After the mysql query but still in the if I need the modal to trigger. I've considered json but don't know enough to create my own code. The javascript to show the modal is this line:

```
$('#myModal').modal('show')
```

How would I translate that to work with my PHP trigger?

Comment: Consider that when php is being processed the page doesn't even exist, and when JS is loaded PHP has already done its work. Might want to use AJAX for that, but the workflow isn't much clear so far

Comment: Good to know, would this be fixed with document.ready and brackets around the modal code? Or should I just set a javascript variable inside php and make the modal trigger on document ready if that variable is set?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add a variable that checks the state,

```
$show_modal = false;
```

And in your get set it to true,

```
if ($_GET['activate']) {
    $activate = $_GET['activate'];
    mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `active` = 1 WHERE `email_code` = '$activate'");
    $show_modal = true;
}
```

Now in your html :

```
<?php if($show_modal):?>
  <script> $('#myModal').modal('show');</script>
<?php endif;?>
```

Answer (score 4):

This is actually easier than most people realise, just inject your JS call into the page using a PHP if statement:

```
<?php if (($_GET['activate'])) { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript"> $('#myModal').modal('show'); </script>
<?php } ?>
```

Put this php if statement into the head of your document (or the footer if your considering load times) and it will open your modal as required.

Comment: Yeah, this was my initial thought too but it didn't work when I tried. Now thanks to the comment in the OP I know it was because jQuery is called before </body> and I put the PHP after <head>- Rookie mistake. Solved it with normal javascript window.onload (jQuery is still called in the footer).

Comment: Yes well u will have to place this code after the Jquery load for it to work.